# ZFS Reporting (on FreeBSD and Linux via ZoL)

Tags: freebsd, zfs, reporting, drive-failure, zfsonlinux

As a longtime mdadm user is was just experiencing a disk error and remembered that I configured a Auto Mail reporting for mdadm on disk errors.

Therefore i just had to insert my Mail address inside */etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf*

```
MAILADDR someone@exaplme.org
```

But I really missed that one out on FreeBSD.
And as my ZFS RAID6 is now running over half a year i thought of what would happen if a disk would experience a failure?

I never configured any external mail address. Is there an easy way to accomplish **and** test this?

Like on mdadm:

```
sudo mdadm –monitor –scan –test
```

And how would i do it on Linux with ZoL (ZFS on Linux)?

**EDIT:** Sorry i meant AUTOMATED Reporting. not scheduled.

I know i could have build a script and parse zpool status -X every minute. but I think this is not a very elegant approach of accomplishing the reporting problem.
It would be better to be notified instantly on a disk failure (like mdadm)

**EDIT[2]:** Thank you for your advices, but no im stuck with some scripting issues, fould someone help me with my for loop problem in /bin/sh here -> [PASTEBIN](http://pastebin.com/RJAcTFdh)

**EDIT[3]:** Got my for loop problem. :) (update in [PASTEBIN](http://pastebin.com/RJAcTFdh))

Any more advices for my script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run a regular script (cron) that checks `zpool status -x` output. Longer-term, the ZFS on Linux project is [working towards this](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/issues/2) in the form of an event daemon. The Solaris-derived systems had access to the Fault Management Architecture.

As far as automated reports, even commercial solutions like [NexentaStor](http://www.nexentastor.org) use scheduled checks. There's nothing wrong with that.

[image]

---

Something like this:

```
[root@mdmarra ~]# zpool status -x
all pools are healthy
```

Versus something awful like:

```
[root@mdmarra ~]# zpool status -x
  pool: vol1
 state: UNAVAIL
status: One or more devices are faulted in response to IO failures.
action: Make sure the affected devices are connected, then run 'zpool clear'.
   see: http://www.sun.com/msg/ZFS-8000-JQ
 scan: scrub repaired 0 in 1h15m with 0 errors on Sun Jul 28 21:15:10 2013
config:

        NAME          STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        vol1          UNAVAIL      0     0     0  insufficient replicas
          mirror-0    DEGRADED     0     0     0
            c1t0d0    UNAVAIL      0     0     0  cannot open
            c2t0d0    ONLINE       0     0     0
          mirror-1    DEGRADED     0     0     0
            c1t1d0    UNAVAIL      0     0     0  cannot open
            c2t1d0    ONLINE       0     0     0
          mirror-2    DEGRADED     0     0     0
            spare-0   UNAVAIL      0     0     0  insufficient replicas
              c1t2d0  UNAVAIL      0     0     0  cannot open
              c2t8d0  UNAVAIL      0     0     0  cannot open
            c2t2d0    ONLINE       0     0     0
          mirror-3    DEGRADED     0     0     0
            c1t3d0    UNAVAIL      0     0     0  cannot open
            c2t3d0    ONLINE       0     0     0
          mirror-4    DEGRADED     0     0     0
            c1t4d0    UNAVAIL      0     0     0  cannot open
            c2t4d0    ONLINE       0     0     0
          mirror-5    UNAVAIL      0     0     0  insufficient replicas
            c1t5d0    UNAVAIL      0     0     0  cannot open
            c2t5d0    FAULTED      0     0     0  too many errors
        cache
          c3t5d0      ONLINE       0     0     0
        spares
          c2t8d0      UNAVAIL   cannot open

errors: No known data errors
```

Comment: Thank you but i just edited my question to be a bit more precise. I meant something automated, not a cronjob or something else.

Comment: Updated. There's nothing wrong with periodic checks.

Comment: Ok, so could someone give me an advice on for loops in /bin/sh this is what i currently got [PASTEBIN](http://pastebin.com/RJAcTFdh)

Comment: Thanks, already got all is need. check the Pastebin link, to see the results.

Answer (score 3):

Try [zfswatcher](http://zfswatcher.damicon.fi/), it works really well for me.

Comment: Ooooh, let me try this.